# Error while running libcurl7.43.0 make in CentOS 5.11

Tags: c++, linux, openssl, centos, libcurl

Before I was using libculr-7.42.1 but due to CVE-2015-3236 and CVE-2015-3237, I plan to upgrade to libculr-7.43.0 which fixes the above mentioned vulnerabilities.

After upgrade It was building fine(make) in my dev-vm which is running in CentOS-6.4. But when I started building in QA mechanic which is running CentOS-5.11 giving following exception. Is there anything to to address for lower version of CentOS.

> [exec] vtls/openssl.c: In function 'ssl_msg_type': [exec]
>   vtls/openssl.c:1430: error: 'SSL3_MT_NEWSESSION_TICKET' undeclared
>   (first use in this function) [exec] vtls/openssl.c:1430: error: (Each
>   undeclared identifier is reported only once [exec]
>   vtls/openssl.c:1430: error: for each function it appears in.) [exec]
>   make[1]: *** [vtls/libcurl_la-openssl.lo] Error 1 [exec] make: ***
>   [install-recursive] Error 1
>   ................................................ [exec] Result: 2

Any suggestion is highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an exception, it's a compilation error. It looks like the version of OpenSSL on your 5.11 machine is older than the one on 6.4. Libcurl [has been updated](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-06/0097.html) for this. (Googling error messages is a useful habit.)

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should try [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there were few naming conflict with OpenSSL old version(< ~ 0.9.8f). Regarding this I raised an issue and they [fixed](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/4a2398627c32c9132b270f6c79492f7bbc5b90c3) it.

More here https://github.com/bagder/curl/issues/323#issuecomment-114492795

**EDIT:**
It got fixed in  [curl-7.44.0](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_44_0) (released on 12-Aug-15)